# Mail to Friend option on Stack Overflow careers replaces space with + in subject and body

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I click "Mail to a friend" on a stack overflow careers job I get an email with all the spaces replaced by plus signs both in the subject and the body. For example:

We're+having+fun+building+technology+that+delights+customers,+empowers+app+developers,+and+propels+Amazon+Appstore.+We’re+re-thinking+money,+and+if+you’re+up+for+it,+you+can+help.++Amazon…

Original ad [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/45194/software-development-engineer-amazon-coins-amazon?a=T7mcZZIc)

I am using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

Comment: Reproduced with Mac OS X, Chrome and Apple Mail

Comment: Reproduced on Debian 7, Iceweasel 17.0.10 and Icedove 17.0.10 - seems likely not client specific given the range of clients and OS already. It's not just that ad either. Tried 5 others at random and same issue present

Comment: No repro using gmail as my mailto provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to repro on my machine, but I checked in a change which should get rid of the plus signs and leave the spaces.  It will be live in a few minutes for you all to try.